# Where can I find Shekalim (Talmud Yerushalmi) in English online?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, english, talmud-yerushalmi, tractate-shekalim

I hadn't noticed that the Daf Yomi cycle includes masechet Shekalim, from the [Talmud Yerushalmi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud_Yerushalmi).  I've been following the cycle using a (digital) Soncino English translation of the Bavli; this set does not include the upcoming Shekalim.  It's a little late to procure a print edition (it'll be half-over before a book would arrive).  I found the [mishnayot](http://halakhah.com/rst/moed/20%20-%20Shekolim.pdf) online in English, but not the g'mara and nothing broken up by daf.  (There is g'mara, right?  [This calendar](http://www.dafyomi.org/machzor.php?machzor=13&masechta=shekalim) says we'll be doing this tractate for about three weeks.)

Where can I find a daf-by-daf English translation online?

Comment: For your specific case, have you checked local libraries? Or perhaps photocopying 20 pages out of a local synagogue's book?

Comment: Oh, good idea -- I hadn't thought to go to a library and photocopy.  (If it's online somewhere, though, would still love to know where.)

Comment: Not technically online, but I think you can get immediated digital delivery with the Artscroll App, and you can pay for only one Mesechta http://www.artscroll.com/app

Comment: this isn't exactly the text, just the point by point explanation which you can use as you read the text http://dafyomi.co.il/shekalim/points/sk-ps-002.htm

Comment: [This site](http://www.themercava.com/explore/shelf) currently has a translation of the daf yomi through Yoma 57a, including Shakalim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a translation by [Jacob Neusner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Neusner) online [here](http://instonebrewer.com/RabbinicTraditions/). It should be noted that the quality of his translations is a rather controversial subject in academic circles. That said, to the best of my knowledge his is currently the only complete translation of the Yerushalmi into English.

Note that instead of the pagination of the [Vilna Bavli](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21847&st=&pgnum=6) (21 folios) utilized by the Bavli Daf Yomi cycle, the website uses the pagination of the [Vilna Yerushalmi](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14138&st=&pgnum=116) (33 folios) which is used in the Yerushalmi Daf Yomi cycle.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like that, in combination with the [summary](http://dafyomi.co.il/shekalim/points/sk-ps-002.htm) mentioned by Danno in a comment, will help me stay in about the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Sefaria recently made an [English translation](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud/Yerushalmi) of the entire Talmud Yerushalmi available online for free. It is listed as "Jerusalem Talmud, translation and commentary by [Heinrich W. Guggenheimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Guggenheimer). Berlin, De Gruyter, 1999-2015".